# Check of Microsoft 365 Planner task was updated, if true then feedback with microsoft graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-plannertasks

I am searching for a solution to get a automated feedback, when a planner task is changed.
Why? We use a planner to assign task to a person in the team. This person can change the tasks details. I only get a feedback if the person finishes the task.
But not if the person changes the other details. The team is big,so I can‘t check every assigned task.

Powerautomate helps not much in this.

I just started using Microsoft Graph and I prefere scipting over using powerautomate.

My question:

Is there an Object that looks at the changes in a specific planner  task globally or do I have to check each detail in the task?
And can I run this hourly every day until the task is closed?

Comment: What is the purpose of knowing what has changed on the task? Depending on the answer, there are a few options available. Also, how many plans are you trying to track (a few vs many)?

Comment: Hello Tarkan, One plann, zwo times a day. The porpose is seeing if there are changes. If a task is changed, make a report about the change to the person which started the task. 
Regards D.

Answer (score 0):

We're looking into setting up web hooks, which I think will be the way to solve this scenario. However, before we have that, I don't think there is much to support to achieve this. Since everything is in the same plan, you can probably remember the etags of the tasks, and see if they have changed, if they have, then send the reports about them. But the etags are going to be updated for any change, even if the change isn't something you care about (e.g. just moving the task around in the board). Also, task and task details have separate etags, the details can be updated without the task etag changing, so this isn't a simple solution.